# Checkstyle plugin for Spring Tool Suite appears installed but I can not access it

Tags: java, eclipse, checkstyle

I have recently installed Spring Tools Suite 3.6.3 and then installed the "Checkstyle" plugin via Help -> Eclipse Marketplace. "Checkstyle" plugin version was 6.2.0. However, although the installation was successful I cannot configure the Check configuration because I simply cannot acces the Windows -> Preferences - > Checkstyle option in STS as if the plugin was not installed. Please help. Thank you.

Note my OS is Windows 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem with STS 3.6.3 SR1 (Platform Luna SR1 (4.4.1)).
I solved the problem deinstalling Checkstyle 6.2.0 and installing 6.1.1 instead - that version works!

After deinstalling the plugin, go to http://eclipse-cs.sourceforge.net/#!/install -> follow the steps  "...From an update site archive" (you will be directed to http://sourceforge.net/projects/eclipse-cs/files/Eclipse%20Checkstyle%20Plug-in/ where you can download older versions as update sites).

Comment: Thank you so much filantropito ! It worked, you're a life saver man ;)

Comment: Since the install instructions at SourceForge are down: Can anyone expand on the steps to take for manual install?
(Downloading the plugin's zip file works just fine)